# Main MVC3 web app interferes with child MVC3 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, web-config, web-deployment

Just some background information here. I am currently using shared hosting with WinHost, and have the following setup

```
Shared IIS
    |______Main Primary MVC3 web app (uses NHibernate & Castle.Windsor for ORM)
           |_______ Child MVC3 web app (not using NHibernate nor Castle.Windsor as it does not need database access)
```

At WinHost, it allows me to set the application starting point, so I can have

```
/ <= for primary app
/child <= for the child app
```

Each app has its own web.config, so it is like

```
/web.config
/child/web.config
```

Well, to my surprise, it seems that even though /child folder is set as an application starting point, it doesn't appear to be isolated from the parent primary web app, because when I try to load the child app, I get the infamous error

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.Windsor' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

I tried the workaround by dumping NHibernate related library into /child/bin folder, but that only makes matter worse, because I would also need to setup additional NHibernate configuration within the child app, even though child app has no need for database access.

So is there a setting somewhere (such as web.config) that I can force child app to be isolated from the parent app?

I think that the last resort would be to ditch the child web app, and turn that into an "Area" under primary main web app, but that's not ideal, because these two web apps aren't related to each other at all, targeting different audience etc.

Note: it should not a case of routing issue, because of two reasons
1. WinHost sets the /child folder as application starting point
2. Under the primary web app, I already ignored the child inside RegisterRoutes()

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("child");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathinfo}", new { folder = "child" });
```

Well, after 3 hours of working on this, I am at a loss. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need to see any configs. Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195193/strange-assembly-name-error-while-visiting-site-from-mobiles/9297327#9297327

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving this by modifying the child app into an Area under the parent app. I then disabled application starting point for /child folder and removed the /child folder from server.

It is now working, although I am not entirely too excited about the workaround.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a solution that satisfies the question or my requirements, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is .config inheritance.  But you can disable that using the `<location>` element:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
  <system.web>
  ...
  </system.web>
</location>
```

So basically you would have to look in your config for anything that is specific to the parent app but not used in the child, and turn off it's inheritance.

Here is an article with some more information: http://www.colincochrane.com/post/2007/11/Disabling-Configuration-Inheritance-For-ASPNET-Child-Applications.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work with ASP.NET MVC 3 (maybe earlier versions of ASP.NET MVC). I think it's an issue with routing, but I don't know what needs to happen to make it work.

Comment: @seanwoodward The setting is [available in .NET 2-4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications.aspx), how are you using it? You have to reorganize your whole config to utilize it.  I've worked on a few different sites with nested applications (one was MVC3) where I had to work around .config inheritance, and this did the trick for me.

Comment: I have used the setting also, but the child site failed to respond to requests. Event when the parent site is set to ignore the route. Do you recall what you had to do to get the MVC 3 site to work correctly?

Comment: Another issue may be that you need to clear modules and handlers, especially if you have a module added for NHibernate unit of work or something.