# Disable web.config's appsettings inheritance in child application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I learned about location tag that can be used to disable the inheritance for various parts of web.config, but one can't use this in case of appSettings. Please tell how can i disable the appsettings part to be inherited in child application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `allowOverride` attribute : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

Comment: i tried adding `allowOverride`, but still when the site is visited from mobile i get the error. You can check the preliminary post [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195193/strange-assembly-name-error-while-visiting-site-from-mobiles)

Comment: The error message in your other post doesn't seem to be related to reading appSettings.  You didn't post the full stack trace, which would probably help to identify what's being inherited.  Also note that for configuration sections that contain key/value collections like `appSettings` or `connectionStrings`, you can include a `<clear/>` element to ensure you're inheriting nothing from a parent web.config file.

Comment: I have added the Stack Trace to that post, you might take a look and help me out if you got time....thanks\

Comment: thanks mate....I added clear tag in the child application appSettings section and it seems to be working fine....If you get time visit the site `http://m.price-tag.org` from your mobile and let me know if its working fine....thanks once again

Comment: That link is now dead. Here is an alternate reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx